# How to add custom container to form

Tags: flutter, containers, scaffold

I'm new to flutter. I'm trying to build register and login app.
but I faced an issue. My problem is that I have this container

```
class Background extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const Background({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Container(
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: Image.asset(
                "assets/images/img1.png",
                width: size.width
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: Image.asset(
                "assets/images/img2.png",
                width: size.width
            ),
          ),
          child
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I need to include this container in Scaffold here to take the design
but I didn't know how can I do that.

```
 return Scaffold(
      body: Form(
        key: formkey,
        child: Column()));
```

Can Anyone help me to do that please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Background` is a wrapper widget.  Do it like

```dart
 Scaffold(
  body: Background(
    child: Form(
      child: Column(
        children: [],
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Glad to help, it is more like others widget that takes child, you can find more about [widgets](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets)